# Is it possible to simulate different vendor gamepads?

Tags: input, controllers, costs, gamepad, virtual-machines

As a developer it would seem natural that I would like to support as many possible hardware compositions as I can, however as I'm not a big studio I have a limited budget, which means I have to get by with what I have.

For things like operating systems and internal hardware instead of trying to buy every single computer component out there I can simulate these combinations through a virtual machine environment.

This leaves a question: **Is it possible to also somehow simulate various input devices and combinations of devices in a similar fashion?**

Comment: By input devices I assume you mean joysticks, gamepads, and touch screens, as opposed to keyboards and mice. For joysticks and gamepads, if you make the controls re-mappable, you should not have to worry about the simulation and can instead allow the user to set up the controller as they see fit.